# Limit connections to location by ip with limit_conn

Tags: nginx

I want to limit connections count to location from same ip and if limit was reached - throw 503 http error to client. It seems that, it's possible to do with limit_conn as described in doc http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html.

But I've strange behaviour - nginx(v1.2.1) just waiting until client finish file downloading, and then send same file again for the pending request.

Here is my nginx config:

```
http {
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
    ...
    server {
       ...
       location ~* "^/d/" {
            limit_conn addr 1;
            limit_rate 128k;
       }
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to abort pending request with http error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault, my browser suspend my second request, until first finished. With `curl` it works as described in docs!